# Restarting android service the good way

Tags: android, android-service

I implemented a foreground service which is working fine for now, the service is loading shared preferences to work with.
Now when user changes these parameters and apply them, i have to restart the service so it can load the new changes from preferences.

My service is started/stopped from a switch , to restart it i am using :

```
@Override
public void onSettingsInteraction() {
    if(pService.isRunning()){
        pServiceSwitch.performClick();
        pServiceSwitch.performClick();
    }
}
```

The callback is listening for settings fragment interaction; now my question is ; should i set a small delay between the two calls or leave them as they are ? i'm afraid the two calls happen too fast and the service stops without starting again.

Comment: Instead of stopping and starting your `Service`, why don't you just call `startService()` with an `Intent` containing an "extra" that indicates the service should reload the parameters. The `Service` gets the `Intent` in `onStartCommand()` and it can then reinitialize itself.

Comment: Good idea ! i solved it and now testing it, i'am changing switch state separately and stopping / starting service with intents, i have most of my initialization in `onCreate()` but it could be done in `onStartCommand()` as well, please post your answer so i can accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative: Instead of stopping and starting your `Service`, why don't you just call `startService()` with an `Intent` containing an "extra" that indicates the `Service` should reload the parameters. The `Service` gets the `Intent` in `onStartCommand()` and it can then reinitialize itself.